# Displaying different languages in CMD

Tags: cmd

I'm not sure if this is possible, but hear me out.

I want to display another language (Russian) in the command prompt window. Is it possible?

I type it all in a .txt, save and then make it a .bat

Example:

```
@echo off
echo Привет <-- (Russian for "Hello")
pause
```

But with that, I get weird characters. Can I include the Cyrillic text into it, or is it only limited to English characters?

EDIT:

Tried to use chcp. When using straight in the cmd window, going to chcp 866 and chcp 1251 makes the promt show the characters and it works. But when using just a .bat file, I get weird characters. But not like O's and n's with wiggly lines on top, characters like equals signs and 90 degree angles. I used the code above and tried adding chcp 866/1251 at the top. Still doesn't work. Could it be the problem with making the file?

Comment: Have you tried running cmd.exe with the /U switch?

Answer (score 0):

You must set it to utf-8:
chcp 65001